# How do I account the number of files and the volume they occupy by size range in amazon s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

I need to get the number of files and total size by size ranges like:

- Total amount and volume of files up to 100MB.
- Total amount and volume of files from 100MB up to 1.8GB.
- Total amount and volume of files over 1.8GB.

Preferably using a CLI tool.

Answer (score 1):

[S3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) CLI tool can be used to run commands for amazon s3.

To get the disk usage by buckets:

```
s3cmd du s3://bucket/ : Disk usage in bytes
s3cmd du -H s3://bucket/ : Size in Human readable format (MB, GB, etc..)
```

CLI reference [link](http://s3tools.org/usage).

Comment: There is a way to filter by file size? Like if I want to know the volume occupied only by files under 100MB?